# Mac OSX - ProFTPD server won't run on XAMPP

Tags: macos, xampp, localhost, proftpd

I am trying to run XAMPP on my macbook OSX. MySQL and Apache run without a hitch. The ProFTPD server isn't running. I've tried restarting. That didn't work. I went into the xampp files and changed the port (from 21 to 12). I'm not sure what's wrong but I've been receiving the following error message:

Starting ProFTPD...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
Checking syntax of configuration file
proftpd config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[62092]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'MacBook-Pro.local'
MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[62092]: error: no valid servers configured
MacBook-Pro.local proftpd[62092]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'

Can anyone offer any help? It would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks like  'MacBook-Pro.local' can't be resolved to an IP, and so is not accepted as a valid server. Don't change the standard FTP port. (21). This question is more appropriate to serverfault or superuser, although you might get answers here from XAMPP users.

Comment: Thank you for adding the proper tag. I appreciate the help!